# Ip addressing of pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

How does pods get unique IP addresses even if they reside in the same worker node?

Also pod is not a device what is logic behind having it an IP address?
Is the IP address assigned to a pod a virtual IP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) is part of a cluster (group of nodes), and [cluster networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) tells you that:

> In reality, Kubernetes applies IP addresses at the Pod scope - containers within a Pod share their network namespaces - including their IP address.
>
> This means that containers within a Pod can all reach each other’s ports on localhost.
>   This does imply that containers within a Pod must coordinate port usage, but this is no different than processes in a VM.
>   This is called the **“IP-per-pod” model**.

The constraints are:

> - all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
> - all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
> - the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as

See more with "[**Networking with Kubernetes**](https://medium.com/practo-engineering/networking-with-kubernetes-1-3db116ad3c98)" from [**Alok Kumar Singh**](https://twitter.com/alsingh87):

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*lAfpMbHRf266utcd4xmLjQ.gif]

Here:

> We have a machine, it is called a **node** in kubernetes.
>   It has an IP 172.31.102.105 belonging to a subnet having CIDR 172.31.102.0/24.

([CIDR: Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), a method for allocating IP addresses and IP routing)

> The node has an network interface `eth0` attached. It belongs to root network namespace of the node.
>   For pods to be isolated, they were created in their own network namespaces — these are pod1 n/w ns and pod2 n/w ns.
>   The pods are assigned IP addresses 100.96.243.7 and 100.96.243.8 from the CIDR range 100.96.0.0/11.

For the, see "[**Kubernetes Networking**](https://cloudnativelabs.github.io/post/2017-04-18-kubernetes-networking/)" from [**CloudNativelabs**](https://twitter.com/cloudnativelabs):

> Kubernetes does not orchestrate setting up the network and offloads the job to the **[CNI (Container Network Interface)](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni)** plug-ins. Please refer to the **[CNI spec](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/blob/master/SPEC.md)** for further details on CNI specification.
>
> Below are possible network implementation options through CNI plugins which permits pod-to-pod communication honoring the Kubernetes requirements:
>
> - layer 2 (switching) solution
> - layer 3 (routing) solution
> - overlay solutions

### layer 2 (switching)

[image: https://cloudnativelabs.github.io/img/l2-network.jpg]

You can see their IP attributed as part of a container subnet address range.

### layer 3 (routing)

[image: https://cloudnativelabs.github.io/img/l3-gateway-routing.jpg]

This is about populating the default gateway router with routes for the subnet as shown in the diagram.
Routes to 10.1.1.0/24 and 10.1.2.0/24 are configured to be through node1 and node2 respectively.

### overlay solutions

Generally not used.

Note: See also (Oct. 2018): "[Google Kubernetes Engine networking](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview)".

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes creates a network within your network for the containers. in GKE, for example, by default it is a /14, but can be overwritten by a user with a range between /11 and /19.

When Kubernetes creates a pod, it assigns an IP address from these range. Now, you can't have another VM, not part of your cluster, in your network, with the same IP address that a pod has.

Why? Imagine, you have a VPN tunnel that needs to deliver a packet to an address that both, the pod and the VM are using. Who is it going to deliver to?

So, answering your question; no, it is not a virtual IP, it is a physical IP address from your network.